# Export Excel Not Working in IPAD

Tags: excel, ipad, c#-4.0, export

I am working in the Excel export in c# .net. I am using the below code which is working fine in desktop and laptops.

```
   homeServices = new HomeServices();
   string htmlOutput = "";
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
   HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
   HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
   HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");
   HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Export.xls");
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
   HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250");

   htmlOutput = homeServices.ExportHomeData();
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(htmlOutput);
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
   HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

But when i use this in IPAD, i am getting the error like

```
Unable to Read Document. An error occurred while reading the document.
```

Whether the above code wont support IPAD.

Note : I had searched a lot and i dint find at least a related solution for this issue. For past 3 days i am searching..Kindly do help experts.

Answer (score 0):

The above code will produce output in PC but, with one format warning, same is making problem in IPad.

You can use csv instead of Excel, you won't get error but still it will be opened in excel.

HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type","application/CSV");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".CSV");